# Codeigniter returns wrong "pagination" results

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have this helper method which job should be to prepare pagination data in order to retrieve it on controller...
Basically this is the code which happens in helper

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
}
if (!isset($_GET['per_page'])) {
    $_GET['per_page'] = 5;
}
$results = $ci->$model->get('', $_GET['per_page'], $_GET['page']);
```

And this is my model which should return data

```
public function get($tableName = "", $limit = null, $start = null)
    {
        if ($tableName == "") {
            $tableName = $this->table;
        }
        if ($limit != null && $start != null) {
            // problem is here with limit and start which returns wrong data
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
            var_dump($query->result());
            die();
            }
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
        }
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Problem is that data returned from model isn't correct and i can't figure out how to get properly data based on page number and items per page....
So in my case if i request data with `paramas $_GET['page'] = 1` and `$_GET['per_page'] = 5` it will return 5 records, but starting with record 2 till record 6. So my question is how to properly request give me let say 5 records on starting page 1 and then give me another 5 records on page 2 ETC....

If you need any additional information please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within your $start variable. You should remember that when using getting the first the 5 records, you should use an offset 0 instead 1. Counting starts from 0 remember :)

The code should be

```
public function get($tableName = "", $limit = null, $start = null)
{
    if ($tableName == "") {
        $tableName = $this->table;
    }
    if ($limit != null && $start != null) {
        // problem is here with limit and start which returns wrong data
        //$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        // use this instead
        $this->db->limit($limit, ( $start - 1 ) * $limit );
        $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
        var_dump($query->result());
        die();
        }
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Yeaa, but this means in my case that i should use params for featching pages like this, which is not ok (page=0&per_page=3, page=3&per_page=3, page=6&per_page=3)

Comment: Sorry still not ok (page=1&per_page=3) returns results starting with 3

Comment: I have edited the code. Put a default value in the $start for the params function.

Comment: Now we are talking! Thank you man! It was bugging me for 2 h :)

Comment: Glad could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working example try to do like this: https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/